# HandledToolItem in Eclipse with Core Expression

Tags: eclipse, e4

I have 2 set of toolbars, one on the left while the other on top as shown below

[image]

Now I want to enforce the visibility of the top `HandledToolItem` based on which `HandledToolItem` is selected on the left.

Let's say if I were to select the `Analysis` HandledToolItem , I'd like to make `Use Cases` and `Backend` becomes visible. The remaining items on top should be made invisible.

My PropertyTester that I have

[image]

Right now the PropertyTester for this is never call. Can I still use `core-expression` for this or all I need to do just show or hide the items on the handler itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an Eclipse bug [400217](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400217) which is stopping core expressions working on tool items. Currently scheduled to be fixed in Eclipse 4.5 milestone 7.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Seems like I have to do this programmatically.